# Append query parameter from controller -UI router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have one parent state and child states for that parent. Parent state have one optional parameter reviewId. Everything is working good, when I am sending parameter in $state.go state is opened correctly. What I need is to append (add that optional query parametar in url) when creating new review (id is populated after making back end call).

This is url for opening existing review with id:

http://localhost:3000/#/planning?reviewId=1000.

When creating new review url is:

http://localhost:3000/#/planning. So what I need is after review is saved (Id is populated) to append ?reviewId=newId without state.go.

```
$stateProvider
            .state('root.planning', {
                url: '/planning?reviewId=',
                abstract: true,
                params: {
                    reviewId: null,
                    readOnlyMode: null,
                    locked: null,
                    editButton: null
                },
                reloadOnSearch:false,
                views: {
                    '@': {
                        templateUrl: 'src/app/modules/planning/views/planning.tpl.html',
                        controller: 'PlanningMainController as reviewvm'
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('root.planning.planning', {
                url: '',
                params: {
                    reviewId: null
                },
                data: {
                    planningChild: true,
                    stateTypeCd : "PLA"
                },
                reloadOnSearch:false,
                templateUrl: 'src/app/modules/planning/views/tabs/tab.planning.view.html',
                controller: 'PlanningController as planningvm'
            })
```

**EDIT**

Tried also to update reviewId in stateParams after Id is accessed and then call $state.reload(). With this approach stateParams.reviewId is null after reload. And I was wondering if I can do this without reload.

Comment: After creation of your new review Id assign it to $stateParam.reviewId and after that you may need to do $state.reload() in order to take effect in your url.

Comment: @ImmanuelKirubaharanS Tried that added:

 $stateParams.reviewId =  reviewvm.review.id;
 $state.reload();

and state is reloaded but reviewId is null. And also I was wondering if i can somehow do this without state reload.

Answer (score 0):

```
$stateProvider
.state('root.planning', {
url: '/planning?reviewId',
abstract: true,
controller: function($scope, $stateParams) {
$scope.reviewId = $stateParams.reviewId;
}
```

call the function if $statePrams.reviewId is available. hope this will help you

Comment: Hm.. not sure if follow. So if reviewId is null, state and controller for first child (root,planning.planning) are initialized. So then when save review I don't change the state but reviewId will get value then. So i just need to updated url to include the id and not changing states or anything. Thanks.